# Is it necessary to use codeigniter's built in form helper method?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I m new to codeigniter developement and want to know that is it necessary to use codeigniter's built in form helper methods. Can I use traditional html code means instead of using this code

```
<?php
$data = array(
          'name'        => 'username',
          'id'          => 'username',
          'value'       => 'testval',
          'maxlength'   => '100'
        );

 echo form_input($data);
?>
```

for displaying text field can I use

```
<input type='text' name='username' id='username' value='testval' maxlength='100'></input>
```

What is advantages/disadvantages of using codeigniter's methods.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can definitely use traditional html code for form elements. For pro's and con's please refer:

[Does it make sense to use Codeigniter form helper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035266/does-it-make-sense-to-use-codeigniter-form-helper)

[Form Helper: Any other benefit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241571/form-helper-any-other-benefit)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessary to use CI's form helper. It's there to help you build forms faster.

For simple forms you might do better to write your own html but for some advanced, larger or dynamic forms it would be way easier to use the form build as it generates the html for you just by suppling it with the input's attributes.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to use the form helper functions instead of traditional html code. One of the advantages of the form helper, I find easier to do form validation, prep input in the controller, and then pass the whole thing off to a simple: form_input($field_name);